# php URL interpreting - can't make custom 404 page loaded

Tags: php, url, interpreter

according to the codes below:
if the url entered by hand is: `http://www.mydomain.com/nonexistingpage`
then according to *CODE 2*; `$_GET['page'] == 'nonexistingpage'`
so `$sayfa` value is assigned as `olmayan_sayfa`'
and I say in *CODE 3* that if `$sayfa == olmayan_sayfa;` then load `pageis_olmayan_sayfa.inc.php` page.
But I am getting 404 page.
I couldn't make loaded even 1  `pageis_olmayan_sayfa.inc.php` page.
All other cases works very well without problem.

Can you please correct me?

**NOTE: I know I can create a custom 404 page via .htaccess but I want to learn the reason of my case and correction method.**

Thank you, BR

### CODE 1 : .htaccess, SEO friendly linking part

```
#SEO friendly linking
RewriteRule ^yazılar/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?page=yazılar&subject=$1&object=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^yazılar/(.+)$ index.php?page=yazılar&subject=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^etiketler/(.+)$ index.php?page=etiketler&subject=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(iletişim|etiketler|yazılar|eposta-doğrula|epostanız-için-teşekkür-ederim|yorum-doğrula|yorumunuz-için-teşekkür-ederim|yazı-ekle|yazı-doğrula|yazınız-için-teşekkür-ederim)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

### CODE 2 : URL interpreting, determines the value to be assigned to $sayfa

```
<?php
$sayfa = '';

if(!empty($_GET)) {$getsayaci = count($_GET);}

$url_check01 = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$url_check02 = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

if (isset($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page'] != '')
{
    if ($getsayaci == 1)
    {
        if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazılar') {$sayfa = 'yazilar';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'iletişim') {$sayfa = 'iletisim';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'site-haritası') {$sayfa = 'site_haritasi';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'etiketler') {$sayfa = 'etiketler';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'yorum-doğrula') {$sayfa = 'yorum_dogrula';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'eposta-doğrula') {$sayfa = 'eposta_dogrula';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'yorumunuz-için-teşekkür-ederim') {$sayfa = 'yorum_onay';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'epostanız-için-teşekkür-ederim') {$sayfa = 'eposta_onay';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'hakkında') {$sayfa = 'hakkinda';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'ara') {$sayfa = 'arama';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazı-ekle') {$sayfa = 'yazi_ekle';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazı-doğrula') {$sayfa = 'yazi_dogrula';}
        else if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazınız-için-teşekkür-ederim') {$sayfa = 'yazi_onay';}
        else {$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';}
    }

    else if (isset($_GET['subject']) AND $_GET['subject'] != '')
    {
        if ($getsayaci == 2)
        {
            if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazılar') {$sayfa = 'yazarin_yazilari';}
            else if ($_GET['page'] == 'etiketler') {$sayfa = 'bir_etiket';}
            else if ($_GET['page'] == 'ara') {$sayfa = 'aranan';}
            else {$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';}
        }

        else if (isset($_GET['object']) AND $_GET['object'] != '' AND $getsayaci == 3)
        {
            if ($_GET['page'] == 'yazılar') 
            {
                $sayfa = 'spesifik_yazi';
            }
            else
            {
                $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
    }
}

else if ($url_check01 == '/index.php' AND $url_check02 == '/index.php' AND ($actual_link == site1.'/' OR $actual_link == site2 ))
{
$sayfa = 'anasayfa';
}

else
{
$sayfa = 'olmayan_sayfa';
}
```

### CODE 3 : According to the $sayfa value, loads the related page

```
<?php
switch ($sayfa) 
{
case "anasayfa":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_anasayfa.inc.php");
    break;
case "yazilar":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yazilar.inc.php");
    break;
case "iletisim":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_iletisim.inc.php");
    break;
case "eposta_dogrula":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_iletisim_dogrula.inc.php");
    break;
case "eposta_onay":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_iletisim_tesekkur.inc.php");
    break;
case "yorum_dogrula":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yorum_dogrula.inc.php");
    break;
case "yorum_onay":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yorum_tesekkur.inc.php");
    break;
case "etiketler":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_etiketler.inc.php");
    break;
case "bir_etiket":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_bir_etiket.inc.php");
    break;
case "yazarin_yazilari":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yazarin_yazilari.inc.php");
    break;
case "spesifik_yazi":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_spesifik_yazi.inc.php");
    break;
case "yazi_ekle":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yazi_ekle.inc.php");
    break;
case "yazi_dogrula":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yazi_dogrula.inc.php");
    break;
case "yazi_onay":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_yazi_tesekkur.inc.php");
    break;
case "olmayan_sayfa":
    require ("{$rootfolder}/load/pageis_olmayan_sayfa.inc.php");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nonexistingpage` is not matched by your .htaccess rules.

Comment: Can you please detail your help for me? I am confused at the point that: In my low knowledge I know that I can't match a page that I didn't cretaed, it is non-existing. And you say that reason is non-matching. It looks like a dilemma but for this case I think that it's not a dilemma but something that I'm wrong or don't know. Thanks user1737909. I did all I can do and in my codes I said that if you can not match GET variable then load my custom page for these nonexisting pages.

Comment: your .htaccess list pages you can access. Do not use that - instead, set a global fallback `^([a-z]+)$ index.php?page=$1`

Comment: "... instead, set a global fallback" sentence enlightened me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some common feedback, not solving your issues directly, just preventing them:

```
#SEO friendly linking
...
```

Instead of hard-encoding numerous rules into the webserver-configuration (*.htaccess*), you should only have a single rule in there directing all requests to non-existent files into your application. The request is then handled inside the script.

The you've got a lot of repeated code. Most of that can be handled by creating an array of configuration data:

```
$translate = array(
    'yazılar'  => 'yazilar',
    'iletişim' => 'iletisim',
    '...'      => '...',
);

if (isset($translate[$_GET['page']])) {
    $sayfa = $translate[$_GET['page']];
}
```

Exactly the same for the `switch ($sayfa)` later on.